# Python Find Forward Slash in a String

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python so bear with me.
Basically I am searching a particular table cell for the forward slash character.  If the cell contains that character, I want to delete the entire row.

```
counter = 0
for row in table:
    if row[7].find("/") != -1:
        del table[counter]
        continue
    counter+=1
```

The code above never detects the forward slash but finds any other character I substitute for forward slash.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why the index 7? Use the syntax `"/" in row[7]`, it's much more Pythonic. You should really avoid deleting elements of the list you're iterating over as that causes undefined behaviour. You can also use `for counter, row in enumerate(table):` and avoid having to keep your own counter variable.

Comment: @marcog: Unfortunately `enumerate()` can't help in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's so many things wrong with that code it's easier to just re-write it.

```
table[:] = [row for row in table if '/' not in row[7]]
```

Comment: If you take the time to answer you might as well take the time to explain what was wrong in the original code

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Like I said, I am a beginner and am just picking up on all the syntax.

Comment: @Tyler: The biggest thing to remember is to never modify a sequence you're iterating over.

Comment: Another quick question regarding this and I promise to leave you alone.  Using the same format as above, how would I delete the row if the element in row[7] wasn't between the numbers 1 to 10.

Answer (score -2):

Could you not just maybe do..

```
for row in table:
    if '/' in row[7]:
        row.delete()
```

Or if you really need the counter to del the row from the table, then just put the counter back in.

Comment: This code will do nothing. The name `row` is defined by the loop and not a reference to anything in `table`.

Comment: This code should work fine, I cannot see what your are saying.

Comment: `del` deletes names, not objects. That objects may be deleted by executing it is incidental.

Comment: -1 It's wrong as Ignacio states. Try it out: `xs = range(N); for x in xs: del x` leaves `xs` untouched.

Comment: I wasnt fully trying to write code i just snapped it out without thinking what del means in python.

Comment: `row.delete()` means even less.

Comment: Seeing as we are not given much context on what row actually is, i think its completely fine.